# R PCA Analysis Error

Tags: r, statistics

I get the following error when running a PCA analysis in R and can't figure out what's wrong with my data:

Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

```
load(url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48336796/data/Y.RData"))
pca <- prcomp(Y, center = FALSE, scale = FALSE, na.action = na.omit)
```

I made sure to replace all NA's in the matrix with zeros.  I also checked the matrix for infinity.  Can somebody please help me understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to run a PCA on character data

```
typeof(Y)
[1] "character"
```

That is not going to work. Either convert to numeric values with

```
Y[] <- as.numeric(Y)
```

Or fix the import step.

A warning that the data object is huge (>200 MB)  would have been appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard Telford!